# Boost battery voltage without regulating it

Tags: batteries, buck-boost

I'd like to boost the voltage of a lithium battery while having the converted voltage reflect the battery's state of charge (such that the output voltage equals the input voltage plus a set amount).

From what I understand, available boost/buck converters also regulate the voltage. Is there any way around this?

Would it be possible electrically to somehow combine/offset the converted output voltage with the unconverted voltage from the battery?

I should add that I have fairly good experience with the practical aspects of electronics (knowledge of components, circuit boards, soldering etc.), but very lacking knowledge when it comes to electrical engineering and circuit design. So I need all the help I can get here :)

Comment: Sure, it's possible to make a converter that outputs twice the input voltage for example. The converter chips are very flexible; they use feedback to get the desired output. With different feedback you can make them do constant voltage, constant current, or in your case, double the input voltage. You would need to make your own converter (starting from a control chip), not just get one designed to output a certain voltage, which has the feedback built-in.

Comment: Have you looked at charge pumping?  That tends to be a multiple of the input voltage.

Comment: Synchronous switcher oriented as a boost and forced to run at 50% duty cycle without feedback.

Comment: @PerryWebb I haven’t come across charge pumps before (though I realize now that they are a common thing), but in theory that seems to be the solution I’m looking for. However, are they an option also for higher currents? I’ll be using the battery to power a laptop and need it to deliver 2 A at ≈6.5 V (from a ≈3.7 V lithium polymer battery).

Answer (score 5):

> output voltage equals the input voltage plus a set amount

A way to manipulate the feedback node of DC-DC converters is to inject a current into it.

[image]

Here "X1" represents your boost converter. R1 and R2 set the output voltage. R5 converts the input voltage to a current, which is mirrored, and pulled from the feedback node. Higher input voltage will sink more current from the feedback node, causing output voltage to rise.

You can set R1, R2 and R5 to get the effect you want.

You can also use an opamp, but the idea here is that, to cause the output voltage to increase, a current has to be pulled from the feedback node. With a negative supply, this could be achieved with an inverting opamp and a resistor, but without a negative supply, a current mirror is a convenient alternative.

Edit: [Link to simulation from](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcZYA4BsB2ATNzZsEBOVA9EdcpBSEBAUwFowwAoAeRABY5xyvUtMOQiRWAd268i-XsKgSQhcjKm1VYgOZ91I9EOyooCgIZKcfNZaLgkzJGHjwo0dEXcBmfOi5hSCQkwXIMcnVgAlc2xjPGjGD2jaWh5g4yToBAjjRgFsjWMUrmhEtIzWABcQBO4jHxrjCEYYMEwaSEpIPA8sdC9EjLAiBEwiSASiLi5KVBDeABN6ADMTAFcAG3KKqujc5KMhUoRB4dHxrC4EXNCQBeX1zYAnYzqDffA4Vie6765wQwaPpI6gQjNUQQpJGD-q8FNooaDosIkhClJAERRftUxE8hORaDk3uhBICGuQwXjFNUqTt9pTEWToljFLjjEyAB7cQYgRhUarxbjgIwAexW5QADqKADoAZwAbkKNiZNPRWBzGDRuSwkETNQQBX4QAAjEzlcr0B4ATxl8sVytVSl83MdHkgQXiRl%20YF%20AEsAHZmh6%20kxrGUPJasQ1KF3crBVVDRF6KWLbVHosQcr2e364DzgIJZkCLej0ObGgDGAGsZWK-RHuV4nZ6wA5ULmxC1swgVCJMAzwO8nMEWsSnKOICLxaKQCY5gArFbSzYc3BGRikONxTAe8C-Q1CoWLmVloW%202XmgMy%20gAW3WJqFD3tfgMQWw%20nA0YLE4l5RlM-ni-tf51RCPV1V%20AsyxWB4w39GUr29aD73teJyEYbBIAgHg4kGbdsF%20K8TAregZT3A8f2lY9T3Pc0ZSFRZFmlehyL9b9rQVcolRVDMbGYVoqmjXidkFEAAAovylOV2M4mVJQARxlFiJJtDjlRksVaPoxjygASjrHJczQ7AbF8AzhESZCiFzdCQnXbBHH1X4ywACxMX1VOleDEIeUN6Glb1F3vaUZXKIUZWVci5m9ejzXoWDpQeE1vQPVgPFqEAADFRCqbhik1I0TQDK1JNtFVUtsDKstCXh0MHZgQEU8iwz8gKHyAA)
Mohamed Gharib demonstrating the circuit.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. A lot of new terminology and concepts here, and a bit over my head, but after some quick research I think I follow along the basic idea.

A couple of questions:

1) Is it a simple matter to identify the feedback node on any commercially available boost module? (I assume this is the one labelled ”sense” in your diagram)

2) How much drain would this extra circuity add to the battery, and will it be draining the battery even when it’s not in use?

3) Can R1 and R2 be omitted if I get a boost module with a variable output?

Comment: More specifically, I’m looking to convert the circa 4.0–3.5 V range of a 10,000 mAh lithium polymer battery to circa 6.8–5.65 V (upper range can vary between 6.8 and 7.6 V).

Comment: 1) yes it's usually labeled "feedback pin". 2) you need a power switch anyway because the boost will draw some current even without a load at the output. 3) this circuit depends on the values of R1-R2 so it won't work with variable output. What's the ultimate goal?

Comment: I can’t seem to find any markings other than the usual VIN, VOUT etc. when looking at a few modules online. Could you point to an example? Or are you talking about documentation for boards or individual ICs?

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit on how the circuit affects the feedback node and what it normally expects? I take it that Q1 draws current and lowers the voltage while R1/R2 acts as a voltage divider rising(?) the voltage? How should I reason when I pick the resistor values?

Comment: My plan is to get a boost module to convert the circa 3.7 V of a lithium polymer battery to about 7 V / 2 A for powering a laptop. I need to map the low/discharged ≈3.0 V to 5.85 V and the high/charged ≈4.0 V to between 6.8 and 7.6 V. A power switch is not practical, but I believe the losses are negligible.

Comment: I was talking about individual ICs.

Comment: Why not use two lithium batteries in series to get the voltage?

Comment: I still need to be able to fine tune the voltage (8…6 V will be too high), but for various other reasons starting with 3.7 is more practical.

Comment: @bobflux, nice, ingenuous solution. And its principle could be used either for the requested Boost, or a linear regulator too, if one decides so. It works as a current mirror, right? If you allow a suggestion: you could write another paragraph about it or simply cite a link with further reading and study.

Comment: I've implemented it and it works great, here's a simulation I made to try different resistors to get the desired output : https://shorturl.at/FIMS7

Comment: Great news then! Have a nice day!

Comment: @bobflux could you please put a link to the simulation in your answer? that would be helpful to others, feel free to edit the simulation and export a new link if needed.

Comment: I just used microcap to draw a schematic, there's no link

Comment: @bobflux the link in my first comment, here it's again : https://shorturl.at/FIMS7 , you can put it in your answer to help others understand the circuit and test resistors values.

Comment: Link doesn't work, probably have to be logged in to see it

Comment: maybe it was deleted by shorturl, original url is too long for comments, here's another url for it : https://tinyurl.com/2s3wbrt8

Comment: I've added it to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @bobflux great! just one note : I'm not the original poster of the question, I just found the post today and implemented your answer in my circuit.

Comment: Glad it was useful to you too then!

Comment: Thanks for the simulation! I didn't see it until much later. I'm actually still working on the project. Since I wrote the post, I have gained a slightly better understanding of the principle behind the feedback system and the current mirror. However, how should I reason when choosing the resistors? What's the purpose of the R3/R4 resistors? Are they needed?

Comment: @bobflux, you mention adjusting R5, while in the simulation Mohamed Gharib suggests adjusting the R3/R4 resistors instead. In the simulation, with the resistor pair set to 0Ω, I can get the desired range with the input resistor set to 50kΩ. With a higher value input resistor, like in bobflux's circuit, I can extend and get the desired range by making the left resistor larger than the right one (I don't really understand how this works at this point). Which would be the preferred method?

Comment: R5 creates a current from the input voltage, and the two transistor current mirror will apply that current to the feedback resistors R1/R2, which adds a voltage to the feedback node and shifts the output voltage. How much it will shift depends on the ratio between R5 and the value of R1 in parallel with R2: lower R5 increases current, a higher value of R1//R2 increases voltage, which gives the same result of shifting the output voltage more.

Comment: You can change R3/R4 to change the current mirror ratio, but it is less accurate. 1:1 current mirrors with equal emitter resistors are the most accurate. So if you want to adjust the output voltage dependence on input voltage, it would be best to do it with R5 R1 R2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick and detailed response after this long! Your clarification is just what I needed. Much appreciated. Do the R3/R4 resistors serve any purpose besides their potential use for adjustments, or could they be omitted? I haven't seen them in any of the current mirror tutorials I've come across. If not, what determines their value?

Comment: If you make a current mirror inside a chip with matched transistors at the same temperature R3 R4 are usually not necessary. On a PCB you don't have that luxury so the resistors help current mirror accuracy a lot. Higher value for R3 R4 increases accuracy but it also increases voltage drop of course, and if it's too high Q1 will go into saturation, so it's a compromise. I'd say you can aim for Vce=1V on Q1, so if the feedback pin is at 1.2V, that leaves 0.2V on R3 R4.

Comment: Thanks! While I was waiting for your answer I made a few searches for resistors in current mirrors, and your explanation confirms what I found.

Comment: With this it feels like I have all the information I need to get started, so I finally went ahead and purchased the required parts and set up the circuit. Unfortunately, I'm unable to get the voltage range I need. I need the voltage to change from 7.00 V down to 5.65 V (a 1.35 V range), but the best I can get by changing R1, R2 and R5 is a 0.89 V range. I quickly tried changing either R4 or R3 to a higher value as well, but I don't get the same effect as in the simulation. Any thoughts about what I can to to improve the range?

Comment: For reference, I got this 4–20 V boost regulator board: https://www.pololu.com/product/2890. It has a 100k pot for setting the output voltage, with the wiper connected to the feedback pin. From what I can tell, there's a 330k resistor between VOUT and the pot and a 16k resistor between the pot and GND. There's also a 620k/360k voltage divider in parallell with it, for some reason. The internal reference voltage is 1.2 V. If possible, I would prefer not to modify the board.

Comment: @Misa Try edit the simulation to reflect the board design and your modification then (File -> Export as link), and post it here so we can analyze it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I haven't used the tool before, but I've updated the simulation so that the circuity reflects the board design: https://tinyurl.com/2jf9tvpz. I'm not sure how to properly edit the transistors and the op amp so I've left them as they were. For reference, this is the boost chip used on the board: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61178.pdf and these are the transistors I bought: https://www.electrokit.com/uploads/productfile/41010/C9013.pdf

Comment: The additional resistors and dividers around the potentiometer made it hard to get the desired range, in that case changing the mirror ratio (R3/R4) was necessary to extend the range, I was able to get the desired range here https://tinyurl.com/5m8mm9wd, when you change the battery voltage slider from 3v-4.2v you get output 5.65v-7v.

Comment: In your circuit first change R5 & R4 and put the battery voltage to min or max voltage then adjust the potentiometer until you get the desired voltage, then change the battery voltage to the other extreme and measure the output, you could get a range that is a bit off due to resisters tolerances and transistors imbalance, in that case adjust R5 and R4 until you get the desired range.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! In my setup, your suggested resistor values gives a range of 0,95 V. After some further, methodical testing, keeping R5 at 700 kΩ and increasing R4 to 7,66 kΩ gives me the desired 1,34 V range. Wonderful! Are there any potential downsides of increasing the resistor values this much compared to @bobflux's original suggestion (double the value for R5 and close to ten times for R4)? Bobflux mentioned different values for R3 and R4 being less accurate. Less accurate as in requiring more precise adjustments, or in some other way?

Comment: Glad you were able to make it work, the original current mirror with a 1:1 ratio gives a certain range that can be adjusted by changing R5 but this results in offsetting the output voltage, you can re-adjust the offset by adjusting the boost potentiometer, but in some cases you can't get the offset to the desired value by adjusting the potentiometer, in your case it was even worse because of the other resistors, in that case it's necessary to change the mirror ratio so the offset can be controlled by R5 while the range can be adjusted by the mirror ratio (R3/R4).

Comment: Regarding the difference between the calculated range and the actual range you got, it might be due to R3 tolerance and/or imbalance in the transistors, you can confirm that by swapping the two transistors and check if that affects the range, I guess that could be the downside of changing the mirror ratio, @bobflux may be more knowledgeable in this area and could provide further insights.

Answer (score 0):

> *From what I understand, available boost/buck converters also regulate
> the voltage. Is there any way around this?*

Yes, this simply can be done but maybe in a way that might not be acceptable to you i.e. instead of the output equalling the input battery voltage plus an offset, a simple solution is to make the output proportional to the input voltage.

This can be easily done because normal regulator circuits tend to use a fixed voltage reference thus achieving output voltage regulation so, instead, use a proportion of the battery voltage to act as the reference then, as the battery voltage lowers, the output (boosted) also lowers but in proportion to the battery voltage.

Of course, this can be modified to what you appear to want by adding a fixed voltage reference in series with the battery before making a proportion that acts as the reference. The booster circuit would still use raw battery for its power source.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Am I understanding you correctly if I interpret the solution you suggest here to be the same as the one bobflux detailed in his response?

Comment: I haven't read it sorry.